# Is it possible to transform a microwave transformer into a current measuring transformer?

Tags: transformer, current-measurement, microwave, current-transformer

I have an old microwave transformer with only the primary coil and I'd like to know if I can modify it to transform it into a current measuring transformer.

Comment: Yes, you can. Are you asking for detailed instructions?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy yes i'd like to know how to do it in a safe way

Answer (score 2):

Leave the primary coil intact, you might as well use it as the output winding.

Make sure all other windings and the magnetic shunts have been removed.

Thread a turn or three of insulated wire through the core to form the primary (I assume you want to step the current down). Use wire thick enough for your projected current.

A MOT core is not ideal for measurement applications. It has been designed to save the very last penny in manufacturing costs, for running at the kilowatt level with forced air cooling. It's likely to have permeability lower, and losses higher, than would be ideal for a current measurement transformer. But you can expect it to work to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all of the coils. Remove the magnetic shunt(s). Determine the max current you want to measure \$I_{max}\$, and the current ratio (N). You will need magnet wire that can handle \$N\cdot I_{max}\$, and N turns of it. Wind N turns of the magnet wire on the magnetic core, possibly using a form to avoid sharp edges. Use some lacquer, or epoxy, or something to mechancially bond all the coil turns. Pass a single wire whose current you want to measure through the core. Make sure you always have a burden on the secondary of your transformer. You may solder a precision resistor to the secondary.